# Is it illegal to modify the contents of the qsort's comparison function?

Tags: c, qsort

I did not find anything about this on the man page, but cppreference.com says:

> The signature of the comparison function should be equivalent to the
> following:
>
> `int cmp(const void *a, const void *b);`
>
> The function must not modify the objects passed to it and must return
> consistent results when called for the same objects, regardless of
> their positions in the array.

Would converting the strings with `strtod, atof` etc. come under modification and result in undefined behavior or so?

The objective is to sort an array of `char *` numerically. If it is illegal, do I have to write my own sort routine?

Comment: The function must not modify the values pointed by `a` and `b`. It can use those values to produce other values but it must not change the original data.

Comment: `strtod`, `atof`, etc don't modify the original strings, so they're fine to use

Comment: I'd say, because converting strings to integers (using `atoi` or the like) is a *totally* normal thing to do in a `qsort` comparison function!

Comment: But surely the conversion to one thing to another would be done locally and results discarded except for the comparison

Comment: @EdHeal That's obvious to you.  But it wasn't obvious to Haris, which is why he was asking.

Comment: "Would converting the strings with strtod, atof etc. come under modification and result in undefined behavior or so?" only if you tried to change `*a` or `*b`.   Deriving other values from *a and *b don't change *a and *b so that's fine

Comment: @all Alright! That clears it up.

Comment: Note that the pointers in the signature of the comparison function are explicitly declared as `const`.  That means it really *is* "illegal" to try to modify the pointed-to-data.  (That is, if you mistakenly tried to modify the pointed-to data, the compiler would complain, unless you'd also, and fraudulently, cast away the constness.)  So, within reason, if your use of the pointed-to data is read-only (as in a proper comparison function it will be) you should be able to rely on the compiler's lack of a `const` violation to convince yourself that your code is kosher.

Comment: @Ed Heal, Re "*why would one want to do this*", To cache a conversion in struct. But then again, you'd do this before calling `qsort`. So yeah, it's not something that one would want to do.

Comment: @Haris, on a side note, if the `char *` did not properly convert to a `double`, what behavior would you want?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica For the conversion to leave it as it is. But both ```atof``` and ```strtod``` returns ```0``` on failure, so what choice do I have?

Comment: @Haris, `strtod()` returns 0 on non-conversion failure like "fred" or "", all sorts of values when trailing non-numeric text exist like "123fred", `DBL_MIN` on select conversions of small values,  `HUGE_VAL` on out of range.  One choice would be to sort all non-numeric values to the end.  There are many possibilities.  `atof()` does not certainly return 0 on error.  It is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting the strings pointed to by the array elements using `strtod` or `atof` is perfectly fine because neither of these functions modify their argument strings.  Note that the comparison function arguments of type `const void *` do not point to the strings in your example, they point to individual `char *` elements of the array, which it must not change. What these `char *` pointers point to should not be changed either as this might affect the result of further comparisons involving the same string pointers, producing inconsistent results, hence causing undefined behavior in `qsort`.

Here is an example:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int my_compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    char * const *sa = a;
    char * const *sb = b;
    double xa = strtod(sa, NULL);
    double xb = strtod(sb, NULL);
    return isnan(xa) ? (isnan(xb) ? 0 : 1) :
           isnan(xb) ? -1 :
           (xa > xb) - (xa < xb);
}

int main() {
    char *array[] = { "1.0", "10.0", "2.0" };
    size_t n = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

    qsort(array, n, sizeof array[0], my_compare);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A function should only do what it says on the tin. In this case, it should only do a comparison.

To aid this, and to try to ensure that this is all that it does, it uses the keyword `const`.

So if necessary just take local copies of the data. In most (all?) this is usually not necessary.

**EDIT**

As `strtod` and `atof` do not modify the strings, they can be used.